# Why to use Ajax.BeginForm in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a several question about Ajax forms, i've read some information about, like ajax vx html forms. And the only reason people said was if you want to stay on the same  page use ajax else html, to redirect to another page.

Are there other things i should pay attention when using ajax to html.beginform?

Another question, is there a difference between using Ajax.Beginform and then writing a script:

```
 $("form").submit(function () {
                $.ajax({
                     success: function (result) {
                        $('#result').html(result);
                    }
                });
        });
```

Or without writing a script, i just don't really see the difference, although in a lot of examples i see users do that ... but what is the point then? if you have this:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "result" }, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {}
```

Another question i could do basically the same using ajax jquery script and instead of ajax, i could do it with Html.Beginfrom and then on submit i call the function with ajax ...

Another thing i often see when i juse ajax that when a post method is occured in the url i have like = ?length=7 (and i have not idea where this parameter comes from) Anyone idea?

There are so many different approaches but there is nowhere said what is better what is best practice etc ...

Maybe if anyone has a link to some reading about that i would appreciate.

Comment: You should really make your post more concise as to what you're looking to have help with. This is more of a stream of consciousness that is all over the place. I'll try to answer what looks like a common idea throughout your post though.

Comment: `@AjaxBeginForm()` vs `jQuery.ajax()` -- The knowledge and skills gained from practicing the jQuery method will transfer with you when you move to non-MS tech; `@Ajax.BeginForm` skills really won't transfer.

Comment: Agreed. However, if you're using the MS tech, then why not use the MS tech. I will definitely agree that knowing what is going on, and how to do it for if and when you're not using MS tech is vital to becoming  better developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between using `@Ajax.BeginForm()`, `@Html.BeginForm()`, and just creating a `<form>` on your page and using Javascript/jQuery to submit the form via Ajax. As you have heard, use AJAX to allow the browser to save on the page and only refresh part of the DOM instead of loading an entire new page. This often leads to a smoother user experience.

There is no "right" way to do this, it's whatever you're comfortable with. `@Ajax.BeginForm()` is just the quickest and easiest way to accomplish this. However, if you come from a Javascript background and want to write all of that code on your own, there's nothing wrong with doing it, other than taking you some more time to write what the AJAX helper method does for you behind the scenes.

To answer your question on "best practices", if you are making an MVC site, then you should use the technologies that are available to you. However, regardless of what you choose, the undeniable best practice is to pick one way of doing things and sticking with it throughout the entire project.

As far as things to read, I prefer books over websites, so I can't help you with quick easy solutions for that. That is also what Google is for.

Comment: I see, so basically this if i write javascript myself it is basically the same what ajax does for me in the background ....

Comment: Right. Make your page, and right click to view the source. You'll see the code that it generates. It actually doesn't create any javascript, it does it all with HTML tag attributes.

Comment: If you want a book to better understand Razor and all of MVC, check out "Pro ASP.NET MVC 4" by Adam Freeman. If you read it cover to cover, you'll completely understand all the guts of MVC. If you just need help with AJAX, I'd recommend "Head First AJAX". Overall, that's not as complex of a concept once you get the basics down.